# sort pandas DataFrame with a column with list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I want to sort the rows of this dataframe based on the first value of the array in the "boxes" column 0.8299769, 0.04913859 in descending order. How can I do it.

```
  classes              boxes                                scores
0   7     [0.8299769, 0.27715018, 0.91143125, 0.54477763]   0.999721
2   7     [0.04913859, 0.35264254, 0.15933079, 0.64380944]  0.999397
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take the first value of the column you want and create a new column and sort that column then remove it

```
df['new_col'] = df.boxes.apply(lambda x: x[0])
df=df.sort_values('new_col')
df=df.drop(['new_col'],axis=1)



                                             boxes
1   [0.04913859, 0.35264254, 0.15933079, 0.64380944]
0   [0.8299769, 0.27715018, 0.91143125, 0.54477763]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, create psuedo column `sort` sort based on it & drop

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"classes": [7, 2], "boxes": [[0.04913859, 0.35264254, 0.15933079, 0.64380944],
                                                [0.8299769, 0.27715018, 0.91143125, 0.54477763]],
                   "scores": [0.999721, 0.999397]})

df['sort'] = df['boxes'].apply(lambda x: x[0])

df.sort_values(by='sort', ascending=False).drop(columns=['sort'])
```

---

```
   classes                                             boxes    scores
1        2   [0.8299769, 0.27715018, 0.91143125, 0.54477763]  0.999397
0        7  [0.04913859, 0.35264254, 0.15933079, 0.64380944]  0.999721
```

Comment: i tried that but got this error  "IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable."

Comment: What is the dtype of the column ?

Comment: its pandas.core.series.Series type

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue, what does column boxes actual contain? also can u include the sample code for creating the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas sort_values class, like this:

```
df.sort_values(by='boxes', ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to add the Inplace=True argument so that it changes the original dataframe, I'll edit the answer

Comment: I thanks but I get this error. "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" even for that

Comment: It worked for me when I tried it on the same dataframe, did you define the variables in the "boxes" column as numpy arrays or python lists?